# how to speed up jobs which take up a lot of CPU time in LSF?

Tags: linux, jobs

I am giving a job (EDA tool run) to LSF. It is taking a lot of time to finish. I am giving it to a large queue and  reserving 20 GB memory. Are there any recommendations to speed this up? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Optimize the code you have written. There is no magic that LSF can do.

Answer (score 1):

-Reduce the volume in the output files or path with less io constraints.

-Find a host that its likely less io bottle-necked.

-Incorrectly submitted mp jobs can steal cpu if you see this take corrective actions.

-if you have hosts with better performance do so in your submit resource requirement.

-read your lsf manual.